# Mark a Table as obsolete in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently we have decided to Tune the database of our Online Application. The database is big and having lot of unwanted objects. So as a first step in Cleaning up the Database, we decided to remove the Obsolete/Unwanted tables. We have got the list of unwanted tables in DB. Now we have to test the application run as previous only with the required tables. For that we need to make sure that the application not referring any of the obsolete/Unwanted tables. Is there any way to mark the tables as obsolete, so that application wont refer them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of achiving your perpose ,i can think of , is renaming tables(add _Old to the name of table) which you want to remove. Once you run your application you can see where all its breaking. You will get a chance to decide whether to use the table or not. Once you revert the name of the table (remove _Old) it will work as earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You can revoke permissions on them so the queries fail.  If you have stored procedures you can look at the dependencies.

By revoking permissions to a certain table, everytime the application tries to access the obsolete table, an exception will be thrown.  And there should be a record of this in the database and application logs.

Comment: Every database object has a set of permissions that allows access to it from various users/accounts.  Assuming you're calling the database using a specific account and not the SA account then it will fail due to insufficient access and it might appear that the table is "invisible", depending on what you've done.  I could go on but this is a fairly important concept in RDBMS so I'd try & get your head around it.